# Web page takes several seconds to load when  <audio> tags are present even if preload is set to "none"

Tags: ios, html, uiwebview

If I load a web page in iOS's UIWebView containing some  tags where the src is set to an external page then it takes about 3-5 seconds for the page to load. If I remove the audio tags then it loads almost instantaneously.

Similarly if the src is set to file:// then it loads instantaneously, but if set to http:// then there is a very long delay.

The thing is I tried adding preload="none" but it made no difference, if the browser is doing some sort of network access shouldn't setting preload to none have disabled that?

(It makes no difference what preload is set to in terms of affecting the load times).

Does anybody know of any workarounds I can use to eliminate the delays?

Comment: you could load the web view before displaying the web view, or you could have one audio tag and swap src paths

Comment: Loading the web page view displaying is going to be a major change to the architecture of my program, and would also take up memory unnecessarily in the case when no pages are displayed (the app isn't a web browser but it can display pages). So not something I'm keen to do unless absolutely essential. I'm not in control of the content of the web pages, so swapping src paths probably isn't feasible?